# ¿Como puedo actualizar registros con Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

tengo un módulo de semestres en dónde puedo agregar, consultar y ahora quisiera modificar dichos semestres. El problema lo tengo justo al momento de actualizar, ya que me crea otro registro en vez de editar el que tenía seleccionado, ¿podrían ayudarme?

***Controlador.***

```
public function update(Request $request, Semester $semester)
    {
        $semester->semester_name = $request->semester_name;
        $semester->start_date = $request->start_date;
        $semester->end_date = $request->end_date;

        $semester->save();

        return redirect()->route('semester.index')
            ->with('status', 'El semestre fue actualizado exitosamente!');
    }
```

***Estas son las rutas que tengo definidas.***

```
Route::get('/semester', [SemesterController::class, 'index'])->name('semester.index');
Route::get('/semester/create', [SemesterController::class, 'create'])->name('semester.create');
Route::post('/semester/create', [SemesterController::class, 'store'])->name('semester.store');
Route::get('/semester/{id}/edit', [SemesterController::class, 'edit'])->name('semester.edit');
Route::put('/semester/{id}', [SemesterController::class, 'update'])->name('semester.update');
```

Comment: Un problema que veo, es el nombre que le pones a la variable para el [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding) `update(Request $request, Semester $semester)` que no coincide con el nombre del parametro de la ruta `Route::put('/semester/{id}',...`

Comment: Creo que tu ruta de actualizar tiene que ser PATCH no PUT